# I ran the exact same numpy python code in IDE and the result is different. How is this possible?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm learning python on DataCamp and tried to reproduce the code in the lesson in my computer using VSCode. Turns out that the exact same code yield a different result.

So from the lesson, the code below should produce `3214.35` as a result.

```
np.pmt(rate=((1+0.07)**(1/12) - 1), nper=15*12, pv=0, fv=1000000)
```

But when I run it (copy and paste) in an IDE, it yields `-5555.55`.

How's this possible?

Comment: One explanation could be that you have python 3.x in VSCode and 2.x in IDE. In python 2.x `(1/12)` this is integer division, and yields `0`, you need to change it to `(1/12.0)`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are running Python 2. Note that there are some significant differences around division between Python 2.X and Python 3.X

```
> python2.7
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.pmt(rate=((1+0.07)**(1/12) - 1), nper=15*12, pv=0, fv=1000000)
-5555.5555555555557

> python3
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.pmt(rate=((1+0.07)**(1/12) - 1), nper=15*12, pv=0, fv=1000000)
-3214.351338524575
```

If you still want to use Python 2.X, you just have to change `(1/12)` to `(1/12.0)`:

```
> python2.7
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.pmt(rate=((1+0.07)**(1/12.0) - 1), nper=15*12, pv=0, fv=1000000)
-3214.3513385245751
```

Comment: Thank you for this! However, I've this in my settings.json     "python.pythonPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3"
and already selected python 3.7.4 in the interpreter. 
What else do I have to do to be able to use python3?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: just add `from __future__ import division`

Comment: Please ignore my last message. It didn't fix yet. @chris_rands how to add from __future__ import division?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous honestly I'm not even sure at this point. I'm just using code editor vscode and install python as an extension. What should I do?

Comment: @Lililashka You can follow the instructions of this article: https://realpython.com/python-development-visual-studio-code/ It clearly describes how to properly change Python interpreters on VSCode.